# Docker intermittently errors with "No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

Every once in a while I'm developing with Docker, I'll get an error that says

```
No such file or directory -- app/models/some_file.rb
```

The file is typically a file from my application code that I've edited recently.

The only way I've found to get past this problem is to restart Docker for Mac.

What might be causing this problem?

I'm working with Rails on a Mac.

Mojave (10.14.6)

Docker Desktop 3.0.1

Docker 20.10.0.

Below is my NFS syncing config if it helps.

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  web:
    volumes:
      - nfsmount:/app

volumes:
  nfsmount:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=host.docker.internal,rw,nolock,hard,nointr,nfsvers=3
      device: ":$PWD"
```

Comment: NFS. Updated question to include config if it helps. IIRC I was having this problem before I started using NFS though.

Comment: Mojave (10.14.6), Docker Desktop 3.0.1, Docker 20.10.0.

Comment: On Catalina, but was on mojave previously -- never had the issue.  Older Mac? Any disk issues?

Comment: It is an older Mac, 2015. If it's considered a disk issue, my hard drive keeps filling up and I can't seem to delete enough stuff to maintain a reasonable amount of free space. I also run this app on a brand new MacBook Air and AFAICT I don't have the issue. Might just be time for a new computer.